# How to add more codec support in FFmpeg library used with Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg library in my Android app to play .ts video file format.I am trying to run sample app given at [GitHub Appunite](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg).

So far I have managed to compile ffmpeg library & build .so files.I am working on Ubuntu 10.10 & using NDK r8.

Sample app works fine & plays file formats like .mp4 & .3gp but it doesn't play .FLV & .ts file (which is my requirement).

Whenever I try to play .ts or .FLV files it says "Could not open stream"

In Logcat it shows

```
E/player.c(28005): player_set_data_source Could not open video file: file:///mnt/sdcard/football.ts (-1094995529: Invalid data found when processing input)
```

I am trying this for weeks.So far I have not got any way. Please help

Thanks

Comment: Try this open source video player library :-http://code.taobao.org/p/oplayer/src/trunk/

Comment: .ts file format is supported by ffmpeg, no need to add support for it. what kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: Hi Rajneesh please check my edited question.

Comment: Ya Rajneesh you are right .ts file is supported by ffmpeg.I was gettng error for some ts files but some are working.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the flv format. Does it work??

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the some `ts` files but some `ts` files are working fine.There may be properties differences between `ts` files.